# How can i parse php variable to my javascript function result?

Tags: javascript, post

I have a script, i have to parse javascript variable to PHP file, i've no problem with this function, in my console i can see that the username variable is sent, it's fine .

```
       $.post("user_add-js.php", { username: username })
                .done(function(data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                });
```

In my user_add-js.php file , i wrote the variable $data with a value but i can't return the value "test", the variable is empty . I guess i forgot to add something in my PHP code to parse the value from PHP to javascript .

```
<?php

$data = "test";

?>
```

Comment: in php you need to output the text to be returned. just add `echo $data;`

Comment: Just a echo, really, i'm going to try, if it's the case, i'm just stupid ah ah thanks ...

Comment: ok it's fixed, sorry for my question, i just had to add "echo $variable" . Thanks Brian (i like your firstname, i've the same ^^)

Comment: If you'd like to return JSON, you can set the content type in php before the echo `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the header

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and also you have to encode the variable to json like this

```
echo json.encode($data);
```

once you get the result to javascript you should parse the json code

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

This solution helps you get you data from PHP in any format ( object, array, string ... )